# how to encrypt/decrypt message for as3

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption

I found something about encrypt and decrypt for AS3

https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto

but the document is not very clearly, any one can give me an example how can I do encrypt/decrypt in as3?

BTW, what is the suffix of algorithms like ecb, cbc, cfb, cfb8, ofb, what's the means. which should I use?

Comment: About algorithm suffixes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to use `http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/` lib. Demo: `http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/`. Further, you can download this lib and there are some demos.